# Java: Time Complexity of this code snippet with nested loops: Data Structures and Algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I was thinking the time complexity will be O(n^2*logn). Is it correct.
If not, What will be time complexity?

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) 
  for(j = 0; j < n; j++)     
    for(k = 0; k < 100000; k++)          
         a++;
```

Comment: Where did you get the "log n" part from?

Comment: **Hint:** will `k` grow as `n` increases?

Comment: Same question as above, this is O(n^2), why log n?

Comment: I think the logn part is just a guess.

Comment: kaya 3, I asked for an explanation of the code. "log n" is just a guess. If I know the answer why would I ask you in the first place?

Comment: Here the explanation: n * n * 100000 iterations, executing an O(1) task, 1000000 is a constant and not relevant for complexity, so in total O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is easy. nxnx100000 is answer. This is base algorithms